# How to access logcat for app from robot framework using python

Tags: python-2.7, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, robotframework

I can launch android app through robot framework using appium library. But I want to access the logcat to check api calls. Is there any library for that? Also can I see logs for emulator? And can I assert logs with tags or api keywords to verify url's?

Comment: Have you done any research? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [logcat documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html), you can run logcat from the command line with the `adb` command.

From within robot you can use the [Run Process](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process) keyword to run any command line program. So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test Cases ***
| Example
| | # <other keywords here>
| | ${logcat}= | Run process | adb | logcat | -d
```

Comment: ok let me try this one I thought there will be library or something so I was trying to find that. Will I be able to verify REST API calls through this. I mean if GET, POST command contains certain parameters?

Comment: I was able to get logs as below
${result}=  run process  adb  logcat  -d  stdout=logAdb.txt

But can I run process in different test cases, I mean run in when application starts and stop logging in another test case.
Can I declare  ${result} as a static variable, so value will be same everywhere.

I am trying to dump the logs in file and then verify if file contains certain api call.

Comment: @user2661518: yes, you can do all those things.